# ubuntu-device-flash fails nexus 4

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Phone Status: Ubuntu touch was installed, but i have to reinstall it because the Ubuntu install is broken.

Im unable to install Ubuntu Touch/Phone a second time, it always errors out with the following output:

```
    $ sudo ubuntu-device-flash --channel=devel --bootstrap
    2014/08/13 20:41:23 Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting
    2014/08/13 20:41:23 Device is |mako|
    2014/08/13 20:41:23 Flashing version 179 from devel channel and server https://system-image.ubuntu.com to device mako
    2014/08/13 20:41:23 ubuntu-touch/utopic is a channel alias to devel
    /home/k1773r/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu-touch/devel/mako/version-179.tar.xz
    /home/k1773r/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/device-97360477eff33a9f63eaf8d65b8bc174344963ee793f2eb99107a81bab62262d.tar.xz
    2014/08/13 20:42:46 Cannot cleanup /cache/recovery/ to ensure clean deploymentexit status 255
```

I did wipe the /cache partition with the "Ubuntu Touch Recovery". This didnt help, so i did it with fastboot. Unfortunately neither this solved my issue.

It is possible to reinstall Android, but not Ubuntu Touch.

While in Recovery, "adb devices" only spits out ? and "no permissions".

How can i solve this issue and get Ubuntu Touch running again?

Comment: Did you also try a different channel? (e.g. you could try trusty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After locking + unlocking @ fastboot, getting root permissions @ android (su was missing), i was finally able to install ubuntu touch again.

When it booted to recovery, adb couldnt talk anymore to it, causing said error.
Following the order above solved it.